# Django Microsoft Authentication: Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django, django-microsoft-authentication

I am developing a Django app and attempting to integrate Microsoft authentication using the `django_microsoft_auth` library by following the steps outlined in the documentation [here](https://django-microsoft-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). However, I'm encountering a "Page not found (404)" error when trying to access `/microsoft/authenticate/`.

Here's the error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://127.0.0.1:8000/microsoft/authenticate/?next=/validate/
```

I have added the necessary configurations in my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ... other apps ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'microsoft_auth',
    'sslserver',
]
SITE_ID = 2 # the id matches the record in the django_site table with the corporate email domain.

# ... other settings ...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'microsoft_auth.context_processors.microsoft',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'microsoft_auth.backends.MicrosoftAuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

LOGIN_URL = '/microsoft/authenticate/'  # Using Microsoft authentication
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/dashboard/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_ID = 'your_client_id'
MICROSOFT_AUTH_TENANT_ID = 'your_tenant_id'
MICROSOFT_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET = 'your_client_secret'
MICROSOFT_AUTH_LOGIN_TYPE = 'ma'
```

And my `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    # ... other paths ...
    path('microsoft/', include('microsoft_auth.urls', namespace='microsoft')),
]
```

Additionally, I have registered my Django app in Microsoft, and in the authentication section, I added the following Web Redirect URI: `https://localhost:8000/`.

Despite following the documentation, the `/microsoft/authenticate/` URL doesn't seem to be matching any patterns. What could be causing this 404 error?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!